# decimal to hex converter function (python)

Tags: python, hex

So this is the code and dictionary I have created:

```
def dectohex (number, dectohex_table):
    final_dectohex=''
    if number in dectohex_table:
        final_dectohex+=dectohex_table[number]
    print(final_dectohex)

dectohex_table={'0':'0', '1':'1', '2':'2', '3':'3', '4':'4', '5':'5', '6':'6', '7':'7', '8':'8', '9':'9', '10':'A', '11':'B', '12':'C', '13':'D'
, '14':'E', '15':'F'}
```

Is there a way to use this code using the dictionary (since we must) but to convert numbers higher than 15?

Comment: You're going to have a problem that it is ambiguous if `'15'` is `'1', '5'` or `'15'`. As written, it will likely prefer the former.

Comment: Is this homework? Since python has a function called `hex`

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing this is homework (since python has a `hex` function built-in)

What you should look into is the modulo operation % and loops :)

I don't want to spell it out but think about how you would break a base 16 number using modulo..

HINT:
Try the following:

```
print(423 % 10)
print( (423/10) % 10)
print( ((423/10)/10) % 10)
```

Comment: I added an else statement (which for some reason gives me a syntax error) but I'm not sure how I should loop it appropriately :/  
def dectohex (number, dectohex_table):
    final_dectohex=''
    if number in dectohex_table:
        final_dectohex+=dectohex_table[number]
    print(final_dectohex)
    else:
        (float(number)%16)
            
dectohex_table={'0':'0', '1':'1', '2':'2', '3':'3', '4':'4', '5':'5', '6':'6', '7':'7', '8':'8', '9':'9', '10':'A', '11':'B', '12':'C', '13':'D'
, '14':'E', '15':'F'}

Comment: I have no idea why you had a syntax error. You can't format code in comments. It might very well just be indentation errors.

Comment: I'm adding a hint to the above

Answer (score 1):

```
table = {0:'0', 1:'1', 2:'2', 3:'3', 4:'4', 5:'5', 6:'6', 7:'7', 8:'8', 9:'9', 10:'A', 11:'B', 12:'C', 13:'D', 14:'E', 15:'F'}

def dectohex(num, tab):
    value = num
    s = ''
    while value > 0:
        s += table[value % 16]
        value //= 16
    return '0x' + ''.join(reversed(s))

>>> dectohex(123456, table)    # the above function
'0x1E240'
>>> hex(123456)                # python's function
'0x1e240'
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn this one-liner in ..

```
 >>> x=423
 >>> ''.join([ {'0000':'0','0001':'1','0010':'2','0011':'3','0100':'4','0101':'5',
     '0110':'6','0111':'7','1000':'8','1001':'9','1010':'a','1011':'b',
     '1100':'c','1101':'d','1110':'e','1111':'f'}[y] 
     for y in re.findall('....', ''.join(map(str, [ int(x&(1<<i)>0) 
     for i in range(32) ][::-1]))) ])
 '000001a7'
```